# Rails cookies with wrong expiring date

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cookies

recently I've trying to set up a cookie in order to validate a session in a Rails 3.2 app.

The cookie was supposed to expire at the beginning of the next day, this way I would force users to login again (mandatory)

First I changed my app's timezone to the one I was expecting to handle:

```
config.time_zone = 'Caracas'
```

After that I created the cookie as follows:

```
cookies[:remember_token] = {value: user.remember_token, 
                            expires: 1.day.from_now.beginning_of_day}
```

The cookie gets created without any problem but the expire date is wrong. In Chromium the date is set to  today a 19:30 PM (Although my machine timezone is set accordingly to the app).

The strange thing comes when I change the definition of the cookie to:

```
cookies[:remember_token] = {value: user.remember_token, 
                            expires: 1.day.from_now}
```

If I set to cookie only to 1 day from today then the expire date is set properly to exactly 24 hours from now.

Any ideas why beginning_of_date is not setting the date correctly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is down to the order of execution. The time zone is applied after the beginning of day is calculated. E.g. I am in UTC timezone, and I can do the following in `rails console`:

```
irb(main):019:0> 1.day.from_now.in_time_zone(Time.zone).beginning_of_day
=> Thu, 01 Nov 2012 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
irb(main):020:0> 1.day.from_now.beginning_of_day.in_time_zone(Time.zone)
=> Thu, 01 Nov 2012 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
irb(main):021:0> Time.zone.now.tomorrow.beginning_of_day 
=> Thu, 01 Nov 2012 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
irb(main):022:0> 1.day.from_now.beginning_of_day.in_time_zone('Caracas')
=> Wed, 31 Oct 2012 19:30:00 VET -04:30
irb(main):023:0> 1.day.from_now.in_time_zone('Caracas').beginning_of_day
=> Thu, 01 Nov 2012 00:00:00 VET -04:30
```

So if you change your cookie calculation to the following it should work:

```
cookies[:remember_token] = {value: user.remember_token, 
                            expires: 1.day.from_now.in_time_zone(Time.zone).beginning_of_day}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mccannf. It works if I explicitly indicate 'Caracas' in the in_time_zone method. I wonder why because I set my timezone as Caracas in the application.rb, any ideas why the time zone is not being recognized in the helper method that creates the cookie?

Comment: Is it possible you have `config.time_zone` in more than one environment? What happens when you run the commands above in `rails console` in your own environment?

Comment: if I execute Time.zone in the console is says 'Caracas'. So far I'm testing everything in my development environment.